# Why is CiviCRM StackExchange labelled beta

Tags: discussion

For the 4 years that I have been using the CiviCRM StackExchange  site its been labelled beta, which to me suggests it might be unreliable or experimental, which I don't think is the case. Its a very valuable and reliable resource. Can the word "beta" be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on this process but you can find [an explanation of the 'beta' label](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta) and a bit about the ['graduation'](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/) process (though quite old).

Here are the [current stats for the CiviCRM SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm)

See also [the discussion here](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/what-happens-to-our-data-if-we-dont-exit-beta?rq=1).